# Write JSON for corresponding XML

Tags: python, json, xml, xml-parsing, code-generation

I want to write JSON code which can be converted in fix format kind of XML

```
    <function>foo
      <return>uint32_t</return>
      <param>count
        <type>uint32_t</type>
      </param>
    </function>
```

I have tried multiple ways to develop a JSON which can be formatted like as in above but failed to get perfection because no separate key is required for foo and count which are orphan values otherwise.

Tried ways:
Way 1:

```
{
"function" : 
  {"foo":
    {"return":"uint32_t"},
    "param":
      {"count":
        {"type":"uint32_t"}
      }
     }
   }
```

Way 2:

```
{
"function" : 
  ["foo",{"return":"uint32_t"}],
  "param":
    ["count",{"type":"uint32_t"}]
}
```

Way 3: But i do not need name tag :(

```
{
"function": 
  {"name": "foo",
   "return": "uint32_t",
   "param": "count",
   "type": "uint32_t"
  }
}
```

For generating output and testing please use:
[JSON to XML convertor](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-to-xml-converter.html)

Requesting your help.. **I later have a script to convert the formatted excel to C header files.**

Comment: How does excel fit into this?? Please read [xy-Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: ...and what's your actual question?

Comment: I want the conversion of JSON to XML format, @KlausD. question is how to handle orphan members like function name foo and param count. it should not be required to map function name with <name> tag, which is happening in way:3 example.@PatrickArtner

Answer (score 0):

It is very rare for a JSON-to-XML conversion library to give you precise control over the XML that is generated, or conversely, for an XML-to-JSON converter to give you precise control over the JSON that is generated. It's basically not possible because the data models are very different.

Typically you have to accept what the JSON-to-XML converter gives you, and then use XSLT to transform it into the flavour of XML that you actually want.

(Consider using the json-to-xml() conversion function in XSLT 3.0 and then applying template rules to the result.)